# Is this normal for my cat to be bald?

Tags: cats, health, skin-condition, ears-nose-throat, hairloss

He is around 4 and half months. I’ve had him since he had opened his eyes and around 3 months of his age I noticed it.  He has these thin/bald spots, on his other ear too. He never really scratches or grooms that area and I am really worried it might be something really bad. He doesn’t show any discomfort or any of that.

[image]
[image]

Comment: It's actually completely normal. It's called facial alopecia, and it's sort of like male pattern baldness or a receding hairline in men, except it happens to cats of either sex.

Comment: Thank you!! so it will eventually grow back?

Comment: Nope. But that's okay. It doesn't bother the cats any.

Comment: Yeah, if it ever looks inflamed or if the cat is scratching it a lot then it would be worth looking into, but this pattern is normal (my cat also has it, though to a lesser degree)